# Restoring a new Mac Mini from TM Backup on a Pegasus R4 Drive

Tags: time-machine, restore

Trying to restore a new Mac Mini which just crashed from its Time Machine backup which is on a Promise Pegasus R4 drive. On first boot up the repaired Mac Mini does not see the Pegasus drive, so cannot restore.

So set up Mac Mini as if new which intention of using the Migration Assistant to restore back to original state. This unfortunately also does not see the Pegasus Drive even though the Mac Mini itself can.

Looked at Disk Utility to move the Mac Mini Backup from Pegasus Drive to an ordinary external drive but that seems to only work for drives as a whole - not a backup folder parked on the Pegasus Drive.

Any ideas most welcome as I have run out of ideas now. Thanks.

Comment: Did you perhaps pull a drive from a RAID configuration and not have it configured as a JBOD? If so, you best either try to reassemble the drives and access the backup through the pegasus controller or open a ticket with Pegasus support. Their support has been top notch every time I've needed them.

Comment: May be related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106013/how-to-restore-applications-files-from-hd-backup-migration-asst-wont-read-it