# How to restore Applications & Files from HD Backup (Migration Asst won't read it)

Tags: disk-utility, restore, migration-assistant

I recently had a problem with my MBP which wouldn't start up. After the chime it would shut down. I started using <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and ran Disk Utility. Had issues with my boot partition but no issues on my data partition.

Bought a new external HDD, created 3 partitions as Mac OS Extended Journaled:

1. Boot Partition
2. Original MBP Boot Partition Backup
3. Original MBP Data Partition Backup

I managed to get all the data saved so I'm reasonably confident I have everything backed up on the external HDD.

I erased my MBP boot partition and reinstalled Mountain Lion. The Data partition remained same and is still fine. Now I want to get all my files/libraries/apps back from the External HDD backup. Migration asst doesn't see Partition 2 and only sees the boot partition.

I'm sure there must be a way to migrate everything back but I can't find a way to do it.
How can I use Migration Assistant with a second partition, or can I use an alternative method to restore my data?

Answer (score 1):

Manually, enable root user, and then you can move the files by hand.

Comment: For my own use and others viewing in the future, please can you explain how to do this and why it would work? Thanks